# Capture a range using R's Indicator function

Tags: r, statistics, interaction, threshold

I am currently building a threshold model that partitions observations into those above and below the level i. i.e.

```
 model_threg <- pgmm(ML ~ ...+ I(A*I(B>=i)) + I(A*I(B < i))+...)
```

I am keen to understand how i can extend this to capture bands of values. i.e. I want to use the the indicator function to explore ranges. So far I have tried

```
I(A*I(j>B>=i)) and I(A*I(B %in% c(j:i)))
```

however neither have had any luck!

Is there an alternate way to write this?

Comment: If you expected more precise solution you have to provide more details. Best

Comment: Hi Polkas - sorry it wasnt clear - the solution was simple - just needed to embed another indicator function within the indicator function to precondition the data